# Let $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\Bbb{C})$, then $\lVert A\rVert^2\le \sum\limits_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over $\Bbb{C}$, then $A$ can be thought of as an operator on $\Bbb{C}^n$. Endow $\Bbb{C}^n$ with usual norm i.e. $\lVert (z_1,\ldots,z_n)\rVert_2=(\sum_{i=1}^n |z_i|^2)^{1/2}$. Then operator norm of $A$ is defined as $\lVert A\rVert:=\text{sup}\{\lVert Ax\rVert_2:\lVert x\rVert_2\le 1\}$. We have to prove that $\lVert A\rVert^2\le \sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2$.

Now, we know that $$\lVert A\rVert^2=\lVert A^* A\rVert\ge \langle A^* Ae_j,e_j\rangle=\lVert Ae_j\rVert_2^2=\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ij}|^2$$ for all $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
This implies $$n\lVert A\rVert^2\ge\sum_{i,j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2\implies \lVert A\rVert^2\ge\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i,j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2$$

But I have to find the inequality in opposite direction i.e. a bound on $\lVert A\rVert^2$.

Can anyone suggest any wayout to finish the proof? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hint: try comparing $\|Ax\|_2^2$ to $\|x\|_2^2$ for all $x$, using a certain inequality.

Comment: The usual norm is $\lVert (z_1,\ldots,z_n)\rVert_2=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |z_i|^2}$.

Comment: @BrunoB Got it, thanks